# Can't access JSON object in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular-http

I am trying to make a weather app in Angular 2 using the open weather map api. I have the HttpModule installed in my app, in app.module.ts. I have also imported Http in app.component.ts where I am running the program.

For example, I want to get the json data for the weather in Houston. my code is the following:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
newdata;

constructor (private http: Http) {}

ngOnInit(): void{
    this.http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=houston&units=imperial&APPID=hiddenforstackoverflow').subscribe(data => {
        this.newdata= data
      })
}

getData(){
  console.log(this.newdata)
}
```

However upon running the getData() function the console does not really show what I expected.

```
headers:Headers {_headers: Map(1), _normalizedNames: Map(1)}
ok:true
status:200
statusText:"OK"
type:2
url:"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=houston&units=imperial&APPID=d3758344ecd26680d1ae2845dcfbbaf7"
_body:"{"coord":{"lon":-95.36,"lat":29.76},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":74.17,"pressure":1014,"humidity":83,"temp_min":73.4,"temp_max":75.2},"visibility":16093,"wind":{"speed":5.82},"clouds":{"all":75},"dt":1508550780,"sys":{"type":1,"id":2638,"message":0.1571,"country":"US","sunrise":1508588841,"sunset":1508629448},"id":4699066,"name":"Houston","cod":200}"
__proto__:Body
```

I need to access the parameters inside **_body** (such as coordinates, temperature, etc) however using data._body does not work.
I am new to Angular and am used to calling APIs in vanilla javascript, where I used the ajax method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old [**Http**](https://angular.io/api/http/Http) service doesn't try to guess the content type, therefore you have to call `.json()` on your response:

```
this.http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=houston&units=imperial&APPID=hiddenforstackoverflow').subscribe(data => {
   this.newdata= data.json();
})
```

With the new [**HttpClient**](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) service that's not needed anymore.